# System Restore noes not show prevous restore points

Tags: windows-7, windows, system-restore

The problem I'm having is that when I go to system restore, I do not have any restore points listed. Just the other day I created one and t was also 4 of them listed besides the one I created, now when I go to restore point, I see none.

Also when I go to try and create a point, it will not let me create one other than a current one. I was trying to locate a previous restore point prior to 3 April 2011. How can  do that? Is that posible? My laptop used to store many restore points, now I dont see any. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using Windows Vista or Windows 7? If you're not sure, go to http://supportdetails.com/ and it will say.

Answer (score 0):

Is the disk getting full? Pretty sure Windows auto-deletes restore points when the disk gets full.